# require('webdriverio') is not working with require.js

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn, webdriver-io

I'm trying to launch webdriverio using Java. I have two files one java file and other test.js file to launch the web driver.

**test.js file**

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var options = {
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome'
    }
};
function launchbrowser(){
    var client=webdriverio.remote(options).init();
    client.url('https://www.google.com');
    client.end();
}
```

**Java File to call test.js**

```
System.out.println("Launching WebDriver IO");
String testjsFile = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "scripts"
                + File.separator + "test.js";
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
engine.eval("load('scripts/r.js');");
engine.eval(new FileReader(testjsFile));
Invocable invocable = (Invocable) engine;
invocable.invokeFunction("launchbrowser");
```

But I'm not able to launch web driver in this case. If i dont use r.js file then its giving error

> require is not Defined.

Anyone please help me out how we can resolve require('webdriverio')

Comment: did you try to check configuration again? http://webdriver.io/guide/getstarted/configuration.html

Comment: yes i have checked configs. Can you tell me how we can call it in java

Comment: did you try with  `$ node test.js` first?

Comment: Yes, that is working fine. But once i shifted to java its giving issues.

Answer (score 0):

require is not a standard ECMAScript built-in function. You've to use third-party require implementation like requirejs.

I presume r.js you referred above is from requirejs.org project. What is the error you get when you eval "r.js"?

Comment: Its giving this error javax.script.ScriptException: Error: Module name "webdriverio" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure `Babel`
From official docs

https://webdriver.io/docs/babel.html

Then you can use a normal `import` instead